# External intent in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, click, external, intentservice

How can i make a functionality in button click where a button click in a particular application opens a different  application like clicking a button can play a specific gaming application by sending it a external intent

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) plugin if this just for Android, but for many things, like opening the phone, sending an email, the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) is more than enough.